# How would I communicate that I updated a MemoryMappedFile from another process?

Tags: c#-4.0, memory-mapped-files, inter-process-communicat

I want to use MemoryMappedFile to communicate between a native app and a .NET app. The problem that I am wondering is How do I tell the .NET app that I am done updated the file? or vice versa.

I believe I could use a windows message to communicate, but I was wondering if there is a better way, any suggested are very appreciated.

Thanks.
Dave McNulty

Answer (score 1):

1. Native app. - CreateEvent(... name), SetEvent, ResetEvent etc.
2. Managed app. - EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(... name)